# Percentage of Area of Manifold of Two Circles vs Another?

Tags: geometry, manifolds, area, convex-hulls

Is there a simple algorithm for determining the percentage of area within a circle which is overlapped by the hull formed by two other arbitrarily placed circles, if any?  An example of this would be the image below:

[image: example]

In this example I'm trying to determine the percentage of the total area of the green circle covered by the hull of the red+blue circles (shown in orange.)

Comment: How did you come up with this question?

Comment: @Christian I'm writing a piece of code in OpenSCAD (originally Blender, but gave up on that because OpenSCAD handles boolean geometric operations a bit nicer) that is for converting digital information to 3D printed pieces.  I'm effectively trying to merge all the neighboring circles which don't infringe upon the holes: https://i.imgur.com/9nXviY9.png with something akin to the top-left quadrant of: https://i.imgur.com/oZJrlFn.png (still working out kinks in the piece doing the generation and have some cleanup for it otherwise to make it look nicer, but that's the general idea.)

Comment: So it can assumed that all circles have the same radius and don't intersect each other?

Comment: @Christian Yes.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Given the three circles with their centers $(a_x,a_y) \; (b_x,b_y) \; (c_x,c_y)$ and radius $r$ we determine the percentage of $C$ covered by the hull of $A$ and $B$ by first calculating the distance $d$ between the line $\overline{AB}$ and $C$:

$$m=\frac{a_y-b_y}{a_x-b_x} \qquad d=\frac{|c_y-m(c_x-a_x)-a_y|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

We then calculate the percentage with the following integral for $d < 2r$:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-(x-d)^2} \text{ d}x = \frac{1}{\pi} \left[ \arcsin \left(1-\frac{d}{r} \right)+ \frac{r-d}{r^2} \sqrt{d(2r-d)} \right] + \frac{1}{2}$$

[image]

To make sure $C$ is actually between $A$ and $B$ the distance between $C$ and the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$ needs to be less than half the length of $\overline{AB}$:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{m^2}}} \left( 2c_y-a_y-b_y-\frac{a_x+b_x-2c_x}{m} \right) < \sqrt{(a_x-b_x)^2+(a_y-b_y)^2}$$

Now you just have to iterate over all triples of circles.

Comment: In that second line of equations can the right side of the `=` be used in place of the left side, or am I misinterpreting that?  Also, can the square brackets be interpreted as parenthesis on the right side of that equation and is `r` on the right side equal to the radius of the circles?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. I just used square brackets to distinguish them easier from the $\arcsin$-brackets.